# How do I equip companion customizations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So each of my three current characters has they're starting companion has a skin reward from their own respective missions. I already have said companion. However, the second requirement asks for something called "Crew Member Authorization". What is that and how do I obtain this?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use different skins for your companions is restricted to paying customers -- either by subscribing to the game or purchasing the "Crew Member Authorization" unlock from the Cartel Coin store.

Comment: That is kinda poor business. I mean not even team fortress 2 isn't that bad with free to plays.

Comment: @AndrewEckert There are indeed a few things that are quite annoying for F2P, but BW has to limit them somehow. The F2P model was created after a year so they either had to add a lot for subs or take away things from F2P. And companion customization is just an aesthetic in the end, it does not reduce performance for the player.